# Highlight current line to line number @@@@

Tags: vim, editor, edit

I use shift + V to highlight current line

If I want to drag that line till line @@@@ WHILE KEEPING THE VISUAL MODE (highlighted), what command should I use?

(I tried :@@@@, but it moves to line @@@@ without keeping the visual mode)

Comment: does `@@@@G` work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can't keep the visual mode highlighting because moving the line *implies* leaving visual mode.

All you can do is re-highlight the line *after the move*…

1. Move the current line to before line 324:

   ```
   :m324-
   ```
2. Reselect the line:

   ```
   V
   ```

Which begs the question: why highlight that line in the first place?